# Simplification of AC symbols in Z3: bvadd vs bvxor/bvor/etc

Tags: z3

I wonder why Z3 is able to demonstrate some trivial equalities by applying associativity and commutativity (AC) axioms in some cases but not in others. For instance,

```
(simplify (= (bvadd x (bvadd y z)) (bvadd z (bvadd y x))))
```

[reduces to true](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/gtXZ), but

```
(simplify (= (bvxor x (bvxor y z)) (bvxor z (bvxor y x))))
```

[does not](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/6gwj) (Z3 just flattens bvxor applications).

I took a look at the source code (src/ast/bv_decl_plugin.cpp) and both bvadd and bvxor are declared as AC symbols. Is it related with the rewriting rules that are applied to each of those symbols? In particular, mk_bv_add (src/ast/rewriter/bv_rewriter.cpp) calls mk_add_core (src/ast/simplifier/poly_simplifier_plugin.cpp) which process a bvadd term as a sum of monomials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is related to the rewriting rules that are applied to the symbols. 
Z3 has two expression simplifiers: `src/ast/rewriter` and `src/ast/simplifier`. The `src/ast/simplifier` is legacy and it is not used in new code. The `simplify` command in the SMT-LIB front-end is based on `src/ast/rewriter`. The `mk_bv_add` is actually using `mk_add_core` in `src/ast/rewriter/poly_rewriter.h`.

It is not hard to change the code to force Z3 to simplify the `bvxor` expression in your question to `true`. We just have to add the following line of code at `src/ast/rewriter/bv_rewriter.h`.
The new line is simply sorting the `bvxor` arguments. This is a correct rewrite for any AC operator.

```cpp
br_status bv_rewriter::mk_bv_xor(unsigned num, expr * const * args, expr_ref & result) {
    SASSERT(num > 0);
    ...
    default:
        // NEW LINE
        std::sort(new_args.begin(), new_args.end(), ast_to_lt());
        //
        result = m_util.mk_bv_xor(new_args.size(), new_args.c_ptr());
        return BR_DONE;
    }
}
```

That being said, the Z3 rewriters are not supposed to apply every possible simplification and/or produce canonical normal forms. Their main goal is to produce formulas that are possibly simpler to solver. The rules grow based on demand (e.g., Z3 is too slow in example X, and the performance problem can be "fixed" by applying a new preprocessing rule), or based on user request. So, if you think this is an useful feature, we can add an option that will sort the arguments of every AC operator.

**EDIT**

*Correction*: we also have to modify the following statement

```cpp
if (!merged && !flattened && (num_coeffs == 0 || (num_coeffs == 1 && !v1.is_zero() && v1 != (rational::power_of_two(sz) - numeral(1))))
    return BR_FAILED;
```

This statement interrupts the execution of `mk_bv_xor`, when none of the existing rewriting rules are applicable. We also have to modify it. I implemented these modifications [here](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/a71bb549c616). We can activate them by using the new option `:bv-sort-ac`. This option is *not* enabled by default. The new option is available in the `unstable` (work-in-progress) branch. When set to true, it will sort bit-vector AC operators.
Note that, the `unstable` branch uses the new parameter setting framework that will be available in the next official release.  [Here](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation) are instructions on how to build the `unstable` branch.
These modifications will also be available this week on the [nightly builds](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/precompiled.html).

Here are some examples that use the new option:

```lisp
(declare-const a (_ BitVec 8))
(declare-const b (_ BitVec 8))
(declare-const c (_ BitVec 8))
(declare-const d (_ BitVec 8))

(simplify (= (bvxor a b c) (bvxor b a c)))
(simplify (= (bvxor a b c) (bvxor b a c)) :bv-sort-ac true)
(simplify (= (bvxor a (bvxor b c)) (bvxor b a c)) :bv-sort-ac true)

(simplify (= (bvor a b c) (bvor b a c)))
(simplify (= (bvor a b c) (bvor b a c)) :bv-sort-ac true)
(simplify (= (bvor a (bvor b c)) (bvor b a c)) :bv-sort-ac true)


(simplify (= (bvand a b c) (bvand b a c)))
(simplify (= (bvand a b c) (bvand b a c)) :bv-sort-ac true)
(simplify (= (bvand a (bvand b c)) (bvand b a c)) :bv-sort-ac true)

; In the new parameter setting framework, each module has its own parameters.
; The bv-sort-ac is a parameter of the "rewriter" framework.
(set-option :rewriter.bv-sort-ac true)

; Now, Z3 will rewrite the following formula to true even when we do not provide
; the option :bv-sort-ac true
(simplify (= (bvand a b c) (bvand b a c)))

; It will also simplify the following assertion.
(assert (= (bvand a b c) (bvand b a c)))

(check-sat)
```

**END EDIT**

Comment: It would be great having such an option to enable the sorting of arguments of AC operators. I have a simple benchmark that compares two AC-equivalent implementations of a SHA1 block. Most SMT solvers timeout (12 hours) or run out of memory on it. I can submit it somewhere (z3test.codeplex.com ?) if that would be useful. This comes from a project on equivalence checking of bit-vector programs, that was initially proposed by a company. Remarkably, one of the comments that such company made was that SMT solvers are very sensitive to reordering arguments of AC operators.

Comment: Actually that line doesn't make Z3 to reduce the example to true. The mk_bv_xor funcion returns BR_FAILED instead. It turns out that num == flat_args.size() so flattened is not set to true...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I fixed the answer, and implemented the new option. I hope it helps.